# Creating xml request using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I need to create request to access to the XML services, it should be processed through a HTTP. Ass says in documentation I have to send  "4 associated parameters and this parameters will work as identification and will provide the request". This parameters should look like strings:

```
"codes=12345"
"user=user12345"
"password=pass12345"
"partner=part12345"
```

According documentation i have two systems for sending the XML file of the request:

1 Through an URL coded in MIME format application/x-www-form-
urlencoded: URL (“urlfile”)

2 By entering the data directly in a variable, coded in MIME format
application/x-www-form-urlencoded: Directly in a variable (“xml”).

According to this my request data looks like this:

```
data='
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE petition SYSTEM "http://xml.example.com/xml/dtd/xml.dtd">
   <petition>
      <number>Country request</number>
      <partner>Company</partner>
      <type>5</type>
   </petition>'
```

I create this request using python library urllib2. So here is my code:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url,  data)
request.add_header("codes=12345", "user=user12345", "password=pass12345", "partner=part12345")
```

But i got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add_header() takes exactly 3 arguments (5 given)
```

So i changed header on this:

```
header = {'codes':'12345','user':'user12345','password':'pass12345','partner':'part12345'}
```

And this is how looks like my code after that:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, data, header)
response_xml = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response = response_xml.read()
print(response)
```

But I got response such if i not authenticated user. What i'm doing wrong? Thank You!

Comment: BTW, have you tried using `https` instead of `http` in your URL?

Comment: No, i didn't. I use same url as in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from urllib  import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

args = {'codes':'12345','user':'user12345','password':'pass12345','partner':'part12345'}
conn = urlopen(url,urlencode(args))
data = conn.read()
conn.close()
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried to do like you. And now i have another error, from server. `Identification is incorect`. But i don't know why. All data i copy and paste from documentation. can i add `args` not like dictionary, but like strings? Thank you.

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy: `http://whatever.com?codes=12345&user=user12345&password=pass12345&partner=part12345`. But be aware that you'll have to encode special characters like space, etc (there aren't any of those in your current example, so just in case you decide to change them)...